# How to properly implement Three.js Channels for Selective Lighting

Tags: three.js, lighting, channel

I am trying to implement selective lighting in my project using the new (r73) `THREE.Channels()` functionality, but I'm running into a snag.

https://jsfiddle.net/Angrypickle/t8f7q3vo/4/

As you can see by the JSFiddle, I have one mesh-light combo set to channel 0, and another mesh-light combo set to channel 1. The camera has channel 0 and channel 1 enabled to see both mesh-light combos.

For the purposes of selective lighting, I would expect each light to only illuminate the meshes on the same channel but this is not the case. Am I using this correctly?

EDIT: JSFiddle updated to follow @WestLangley's suggestions. The effect of both meshes receiving both light sources is far more pronounced with white light instead of red and blue.

Comment: Either this feature was not properly implemented, or the intended behavior is different than you expect. You can file a bug report on the three.js site, but try the dev branch first, where channel has been renamed to layer. To prevent confusion, make your spheres white.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, sir! Followed your advice but the problem seems unresolved. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: i know this is old, but they are actively working on this feature